# How Do I Click On This "Sign In" Link Using Selenium & Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
quicknav">
<div class="status-loggedin" style="display:none;" data-component="quicknav-status-loggedin">
<div class="status-loggedout" data-component="quicknav-status-loggedout">
<a class="login-link" data-component="quicknav-login-link" rel="nofollow" title="Sign In" href="#">Sign In</a>
<a class="create-account-link" data-component="quicknav-create-account-link" rel="nofollow" title="Create Your Account" href="#">Create Your Account</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried using below but not working. Please help:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'userInfoQuickNav'/ title = 'Sign In'"));
```

Comment: What happened when you tried recording this automation with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath isn't valid and it doesn't match HTML you provided. What you do you mean "not working"? Nothing happens or exceptions? If there are exceptions, post exact stacktrace please.

Here I can take a guess.

```
WebElement linkSignIn = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@id, 'userInfoQuickNav')]//a[@title='Sign In']")));
linkSignIn.click();
```

You can also use CSS selector, which is better.

```
By.cssSelector("[id*='userInfoQuickNav'] a[title='Sign In']")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `linkText`,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Sign In"))).click();
```